# c# add a list of items to combobox ordered by string not natural

Tags: c#, combobox, natural-sort

i use this code to add a numbers to combobox

```
 for (int i = 15; i < 250; i++)
 {
   cbSumFrom.Items.Add(i);
 }
```

the problem is that i get something like

```
100

101

......
```

but  i  want like

```
15

16

17

......
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: Is it that the 100, 101... appears before 15, 16, 17... ?

Comment: You are already adding the values chronologically, which means that you have a sort order set on the combo. Remove the Sorting from the combo and it should display correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `ComboBox.Sorted` property. If it is `True` then you get your unwanted behavior (default, string-based sort.) Since you are populating the combo box from what looks like a presorted list, make sure that `ComboBox.Sorted` is set to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is is that it appears the combo box is sorting the item and it's doing an ASCII comparison on each character to do it, so 100 comes before 15 because 10 is before 15.  Take the sorting off the combo box and it should list them in the order you;ve added them

Comment: @Haim Yes see me answer update, should be a simple case of setting 'Sorted = False'. Try doing the and let me know if that fixes it or not

Answer (score 1):

Try this...didn't tested it but try this...

```
 cbSumFrom.Items.Clear();
 for (int i = 15; i < 250;)
     {
       cbSumFrom.Items.Add(Convert.toString(i));

     }
```

Comment: Error 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition for 'toString'

Comment: and attach insertion sort with that combobox